# How would I play this piano bassline?

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

The two notes (A) in the bass clef seem to be played at the same time. However, this is music for piano, so I can't seem to figure this one out.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this case, the half-note `A` is struck ("articulated") at the same time as the eighth-note `A`. However, while the eighth-note `A` only lasts (brace yourself!) for one eighth note, the half-note `A` must be sustained.

As such, **you simply hold this `A` down for the rest of the measure.**

And, while I'm here, the notation in the left hand is a bit suspect, since the half-note `A` crosses the mid-measure boundary; this is usually considered bad practice. I thought I'd supply a better alternative:

[image]

Comment: Depending on where you encounter this piece, this might get tricky with the fingering I imagine.